# Change datetimepicker dates according to selected option

Tags: jquery, datetimepicker

I have select box with some values, on change of option values datepickertime dates should be update like enable and disable. if I selected the ready to move previous dates should be disable, if I selected completed all dates should be enabled.

My Html:

```
<div class="form-input left clearfix">
    <select name="progress" id="progress" class="chosen-select">
        <option value="0">Select Stage</option>
        <option value="ready-to-move">Ready To Move</option>
        <option value="completed">Completed</option>
    </select>
</div>
```

My script is:

```
$('#progress').change(function() {
    if ($(this).val() == 'completed') {
        $('#poss').datetimepicker({
            startDate: '01/01/2015',
            format: 'd/m/Y',
            timepicker: false,
        });
    } else {
        $('#poss').datetimepicker({
            minDate: 'today',
            format: 'd/m/Y',
            timepicker: false,
        });
    }
});
```

If I select completed option for first time and after another option it is working well. When I change the options randomly condition is not working.

Comment: is it bootstrap's datetimepicker?

Comment: What does this question have to do with jQuery Validate?  Please only use the [tag:jquery-validate] tag when the question is related to this plugin.  Edited.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suppose you don't have to do it two times in if/else:

```
$('#progress').change(function(){
   $this = $(this);
   $('#poss').datetimepicker({
       startDate: $this.val()=='completed' ? '01/01/2015' : false,
       minDate:$this.val() != 'completed' ? 'today' : false,
       format:'d/m/Y',
       timepicker:false
    });
});
```